# Oracle 11g benchmarks

Tags: oracle11g

Maybe it's just me, but I have having a hell of a hard time finding some good benchmarks for Oracle 11g. If I try to do the same for MySQL, I get a ton of results for read/write performance in different scenarios across different hardware setups with different types of reads/writes. What are some good resources for benchmarks like this for Oracle's database?

I am trying to decide between using a MySQL Cluster or Oracle 11g, and before I fork over my money for Oracle and whip up some benchmark tests, I would like to see benchmarks from others.

Comment: maybe a good topic, just not for this forum...

Comment: Admittedly, I was a little iffy on posting this question. However, my goal is not to garner an answer regarding the speed of 11g, but rather identify a good resource. The most informative resource would be the best answer. I would understand closing this question, but at the same time, I think it does fit the question and answer model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at swingbench (http://dominicgiles.com/swingbench.html) and of course the TPC site. However generic benchmarks will not be useful to decide what best suites your specific requirements. It is more useful to generate a benchmark that mimics your specific application.